# Convert Standard.Natural to Ada.Containers.Count_Type

Tags: type-conversion, containers, ada

I instanced the Ada.Containers.Vectors generic package like this:

```
package My_Vectors is new Ada.Containers.Vectors(
    Element_Type => My_Type, 
    Index_Type => Natural);
```

Say, I have a vector and a Standard.Natural value declared:

```
Foo_Vector: My_vectors.Vector;
Bar_Natural: Natural := 4;
```

If I call

```
Foo_Vector.Set_Length(Bar_Natural);
```

I get the following error

```
expected type "Ada.Containers.Count_Type"
found type "Standard.Natural"
```

Is there a way to **cast Bar_Natural to be of Ada.Containers.Count_Type**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, I was too stupid to actually read all that my error said. I tried converting the Natural using:

```
Ada.Containers.Vectors.Count_Type(Bar_Natural)
```

**Which makes zero sense!**
Reading the error, it is trivial to see that Count_Type is defined in package Ada.Containers.

The correct conversion would therefore be:

```
Ada.Containers.Count_Type(Bar_Natural);
```

Giving

```
Foo_Vector.Set_Length(Ada.Containers.Count_Type(Bar_Natural));
```

Comment: Thanks. Forgot to do that, since you only can after a day or so.